# How does android send SMS and MMS?

Tags: android, sms, send, mms

In android sources, I found isms interface, which uses SmsManager.

What class implements this interface?  How does it work?
What happens when this method is called, for example sendText?

Comment: I am doing something similar HERE!!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14452808/sending-and-receiving-mms-in-android

Answer (score 0):

Use the below link for sending sms.
Use SmsManager. Here is a [sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/SMS/Sender/) showing the basics of sending an SMS, either through the default client or by using SmsManager. I do not believe there is a public API to send MMS, though.

[LINK1](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/sms-messaging-android)

[LINK2](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/SMS/Sender/)

or simply use the below code to launch the native Message box

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
//use to fill the sms body
sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "Hi this is test sms"); 
sendIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
startActivity(sendIntent);
```

Comment: I now haw to send sms from android. I whant to now haw it happend. How ISms intarface sending it. May be some class implements this intarface. Yet I have not found how it works and ask for help.